# For any language $A$, there is $B$ such that $A \le _T B$ but $B \nleq _T A$

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability

I am trying to come up with a proof for the following:

> For any language $A$, there exists a language $B$ such that $A \le_{\mathrm{T}} B$ but B $\nleq_{\mathrm{T}} A$.

I was thinking of letting $B$ be $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$, but I realize that not all languages are Turing reducible to $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$, so $A \le _T B$ would not hold.
What other choice of $B$ do I have that would allow me to write a TM which uses an oracle for $B$ to decide $A$?

Thanks!

Comment: How about $B = NP^A$?

Comment: Think of the halting problem on Turing machines with oracle $A$.

Comment: an oracle for $Halt_{TM}$ could be used t solve recursively enumerable languages, but what about languages that are not recursively enumerable, like $A_{TM}^C$?

Comment: @WillardZhan Could you elaborate on this? Are you saying $B=\{<M,x>|\text{M is an oracle TM with an oracle for A, and M accepts x}\}$?

Comment: @WillardZhan Could you please point me towards what I should look for in the halting problem? I don't understand how the halting problem should be used to answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Eugene How can knowing if A is solvable in non-polynomial time help decide A? I have been stuck on my question for days without progress, any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @user1354784 Turing machines with oracle $A$ can be enumerated. So try to use the standard diagonalization, where the only change is that for every $\alpha\in\Sigma^*$, $M_\alpha$ represents an oracle TM with oracle $A$ instead of a normal TM.

Comment: @WillardZhan I see, so essentially I do the same contradiction as with $A_{TM}$ only now it is with TMs that have an oracle for A. So I can disprove B<A. However, how can I use $B=\{<M,x>|M\text{ is a TM with oracle for A that accepts x}\}$ to show A<B, because I need to query B with a TM as well as the input. Suppose I want to know if w is in A, then I will query run B on <M,w>, but what should M be in that case? Can we ask oracle TMs to give us an element of their language? Is so, M could be any element of B, but I am not sure if we can ask oracle TMs to output a random input they accept.

Comment: @user1354784 $M$ can be an oracle machine that simply calls $A$ once on the input (which is $x$).

Comment: Since we require this to work for _all_ languages $A$, we can't take $B$ to be a single fixed language ($A_{\mathrm{TM}}$ or anything else) because that would fail for $A=B$ -- we would have $A\leq_{\mathrm{T}}B$ but also $B\leq_{\mathrm{T}}A$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, but B is not fixed, it is built knowing what A is. If we are given some A, we build a B that accepts every oracle TM with an oracle for this specific A that accepts strings in A. If we are given a different A, the list of TMs in B will be different.

Comment: @user1354784 Exactly. I meant that comment as another explanation of why we can't take $B=A_{\mathrm{TM}}$ as you had suggested (and already rejected, for a different reason) in your question. I forgot to explain that that was the point I was making -- sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: How can I show $A \lt _{TM} B=\{<M,x>|M\text{ is a TM with oracle for A that accepts x}\}$? then

Comment: @user1354784 Suppose you have a Turing machine M with an Oracle for A. This machine checks if the input x is in A and accepts if it is and rejects if it isn't. To Turing-reduce A to B, on input x, you imagine you have an oracle for B and check if <M, x> is in B. It's in B iff A accepts x. Therefore, you can decide A. This is essentially just the Turing jump https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump. You can prove that B is not Turing reducible to A by using the exact same diagonalization proof used to prove that A(TM) is not decidable.

Comment: @Eugene This is with respect to *Turing reducibility*, not polynomial-time reducibility. NP, P, EXP, etc. are all subsumed within "computable," so $NP^A$ is no more complicated (in the Turing sense) than $A$ itself.

Comment: If this question was just For any language , there exists a language  such that B ≰, could we let B be $A_{TM}$? Would that be an issue if $A = A_{TM}$ since we're dealing with a universal quantifier

Answer (score 1):

Let $B=A'$, the Turing jump of $A$. This is a [basic result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree#Basic_properties_of_the_Turing_degrees) in the theory of the Turing degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Before diving into the *good* answer - namely, that we can [relativize the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump) to assign to each language $X$ a language $X'$ such that (among other things) $X<_TX'$ - it's worth seeing the *silly* answer:

- [Cantor showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) that there are uncountably many languages.
- But every specific language $A$ can only compute countably many languages: a single Turing machine can only possibly yield one reduction from a given language $A$, and there are only countably many Turing machines.

So in fact we know, without doing any serious work, that:

> For every language $A$, **most (= all but countably many)** languages $B$ satisfy $B\not\le_TA$.

Now we combine this with the *Turing join*: given languages $X,Y$, the join $X\oplus Y$ consists of "interleaving" $X$ and $Y$. There are various ways to define it - e.g. thinking of $X$ and $Y$ as sets of naturals, we usually let $X\oplus Y=\{2i: i\in X\}\cup\{2i+1: i\in Y\}$ - but the important feature is that $X\oplus Y\ge_TX,Y$ *(and in fact is their $\le_T$-least upper bound)*.

So we can apply the above, to get:

> For every language $A$, **most (= all but countably many)** languages $B$ satisfy $A<_TA\oplus B$.

---

This then raises the question of giving a *non-stupid* proof, namely a natural way to produce a language strictly more complicated than a given one, and this is what the Turing jump is for; but it's worth understanding this nonconstructive argument on its own.